# Query to check whether a column is nullable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, nullable

Query to check whether a column is nullable (null values are allowed in the column or not).
It should preferably return yes/no or 1/0 or true/false.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You could also use the [`COLUMNPROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174968.aspx) and [`OBJECT_ID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) metadata functions:

```
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('SchemaName.TableName', 'U'), 'ColumnName', 'AllowsNull');
```

Answer (score 98):

You could retrieve that from `sys.columns`:

```
select  is_nullable 
from    sys.columns 
where   object_id = object_id('Schema.TheTable') 
        and name = 'TheColumn'
```

Answer (score 24):

You can also check all columns in a table for 'nullable' property or any other property that you want, for example table named Bank.Table we need to query

`column name`, `data type`, `Character Max Length`,  `is nullable`

Use SQL Information_Schema like this example:

```
SELECT 
COL.COLUMN_NAME, 
COL.DATA_TYPE, 
COL.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
COL.IS_NULLABLE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS COL 
WHERE COL.TABLE_NAME = 'Bank'
```

The result should be like this:

[image: Query Results]